# azure vm creation using puppet module

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, puppet

i'm getting the error below when i want to create a vm on azure :

does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope

I created an application on the classic portal and followed this tutorial :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/

after that i created a resource group on the new portal and assigned owner to this application.

I'm using this puppet script to create the vm :

```
azure_vm { 'sample':
    ensure         => present,
    location       => 'westus',
    image          => 'canonical:ubuntuserver:14.04.2-LTS:latest',
    user           => 'azureuser',
    password       => 'Password',
    size           => 'Standard_A0',
    resource_group => 'puppettest123',
}
```

when i run it i get this exact error :

```
Error: {"error"=>{"code"=>"AuthorizationFailed", "message"=>"The client '5b0bc6d-fcad-4223-8527-a2c9afc2661' with object id '5b0bc6d-fcad-4223-8527-a2c9afc2661' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/5ad96a9-45de-4fe1-91e8-2514dd5e6a9'."}}
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Azure_vm[sample]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: {"error"=>{"code"=>"AuthorizationFailed", "message"=>"The client '5b0bc6d-fcad-4223-8527-a2c9afc2661' with object id '5b0bc6d-fcad-4223-8527-a2c9afc2661' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/5ad96a9-45de-4fe1-91e8-2514dd5e6a9'."}}
```

https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/azure

Any ideas on how i can fix this issue ?

**I fixed the problem using this command : 
azure role assignment create --objectId 7dbc8265-51ed-4038-8e13-31948c7f4ce7 -o Owner -c /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/**

Comment: You will get better help if you identify what of the code you have copied is causing the error. Otherwise, SO contributors would be required to follow the exact same tutorial.

Comment: @Jonathon i think part of the reason why the question is raised is that the asker isn't sure what part of the code is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

azure role assignment create --objectId 7dbc8265-51ed-4038-8e13-31948c7f4ce7 -o Owner -c /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/